# How to work with complex numbers in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, numbers, complex-numbers, operations

I have an assignment to write a prolog code to add, multiply, subtract and divide complex numbers. However, I'm not sure how to portray imaginary numbers in prolog!

```
kompl_mul(komplex(A1,B1),komplex(A2,B2),komplex(A,B)) :-
   A is A1*A2 - B1*B2,
   B is A1*B2 - A2*B1.
```

This is how I would start off with the multiplication rule, but how do I implement a+b*i? How can I show that B is b*i?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: It looks like you're off to a good start with a representation, which is that `a+bi` is represented as `komplex(a, b)`, yes? So your quesiton of *How can I show that B is bi* seems you're not understanding your representation? You do not need to literally represent it as `a+bi`. Or are you asking how to input and output that specific format to the user? You've shown a correct formula for multiplication. So if you have `komplex(A1, B1)` and `komplex(A2, B2)` what do you suppose `A` and `B` are in `komplex(A, B)` if it's the sum of the first two?

Comment: [This article](http://130.216.33.163/courses/compsci367s2c/resources/prologLectures/L7-OperatorsAndArithmetic.pdf) provides an implementation of arithmetic for complex numbers in Prolog.